# Why is PhantomJS rejecting the JavaScript in my HTML file?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

For the sake of development, `process.js` currently looks like this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.open(system.args[1], 'rb'); // also tried 'r'
page.content = file.read;
// page.evaluate(function(){
// });
// commented out so we know evaluate() is not causing the problem
system.stdout.write(page.content);
page.close
phantom.exit();
```

I'm calling it from the command line using a PhantomJS gem for Ruby:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'tempfile'
=> false
[2] pry(main)> file = Tempfile.new("foo")
=> #<File:/var/folders/k9/vnpft_6d7qs6xmdb9_4svvmw0000gn/T/foo20141103-1483-gtxc88>
[3] pry(main)> file.write('<html><body><script>document.write("Hello World");</script></body></html>')
=> 73
[4] pry(main)> file.rewind
=> 0
[5] pry(main)> result = Phantomjs.run("./app/assets/javascripts/process.js", file.path);
[6] pry(main)> result
=> "<html><head></head><body>function read() {\n    [native code]\n}</body></html>"
```

Note the unexpected `{\n[native code]\n}`.

Why is not importing the JavaScript?

Comment: JavaScript functions are called by adding `()`. So `file.read();` and `page.close();`. Is this the problem?

Comment: Thank you both. That fixed it. Betraying my background in Ruby, where parenthesis are not required when you don't provide an argument.